# Sharepoint list deleting from powershell

Tags: powershell

I have got a Sharepoint list. I updeted it in job everyday and everyday refresh by powershell. I have got some column on this sharepoint list. One of this column called [nazwazdarzenia]. And the code which works for today great was:

```
    # Delete existing List Data, If not required remove this line
$Items = $list.GetItems()
$Items | ForEach-Object{
        $list.GetItemById($_.Id).Delete()}
```

But now, I want to delete everyrecord without record which have got in column [nazwazdarzenia] =! "Szkolenie". So delete all records without records with column [nazwazdarzenia] not equal "Szkolenie". What If I should add to PowerShell to dellete all records without "Szkolenie". Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
$list.Items | ? {$_["nazwazdarzenia"] -ne "Szkolenie"} | % {$list.GetItemById($_.Id).Delete()}
```

Comment: Great hack code :)

Comment: Work brilliant :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$web = Get-SPWeb <SharePoint URL>
$listName = "LIST NAME HERE"
$list = $web.Lists[$listName]
$items = $list.Items | Where {$_["nazwazdarzenia" ] -ne "Szkolenie"}
foreach($item in $items)
{
Write-Host "Deleting " $item.ID
$item.Delete()
}
```